# How to perform custom certificate validation with WebSocket

Tags: c#, websocket

I'm attempting to get client and server applications (developed in C# and .NET)  using secure web sockets to validate the certificates within the applications.

Is there a mechanism for a WebSocket (`System.Net.Websockets.WebSocket` in .NET) using a secure (wss) connection to perform custom validation on a client certificate? And similarly a client WebSocket to perform custom validation of the server certificate?

For example, with the .NET class `SSLStream` a `RemoteCertificateValidationCallback` can be passed to the constructor. I assume there is a similar mechanism for WebSockets but I can't seem to find any examples or documentation.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with the websocket client implementation and could not find any way to do that using System.Net.Websockets.WebSocket. 
I solved it using a System.Net.Sockets.Socket to establish the connection and then implement the client-server handshake to upgrade the Socket connection to a websocket connection with the websocket server, and also implemented other methods to send messages and to continuously read for incoming data, simulating the WebSocket behavior (you can find how to do that in several code examples and open source websocket libraries, i.e. https://github.com/kerryjiang/WebSocket4Net ).